# Identifying a cell by clicking on it, from an open user form

Tags: vba, select, cell, userform

Is it possible to use the mouse to select a cell whilst a user form is open, then programmatically transfer that cell address into the user form (similar to defining a data source range for a chart)??

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need to do two things:

**1 - Show your UserForm as Modeless, to do so:**

```
Sub ShowUserForm()
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

**2 - In the worksheet code, you will need to add an action under the SelectionChange:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If UserForm1.Visible Then
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Target.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks